# Is there a way to run a Mininet command while Mininet is executing another command?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, mininet

I have created a simple network emulation in Mininet.

`h1 ---------------- h2` (without a switch or anything in between)

I am running an **iperf** server on h2 and an **iperf** client on h1.

Then I am perfoming the measurment from h1 to h2 in some interval repeated.

But in the same time I want to run a ping from h1 to h2, to see the ping differences while h1 and h2 are performing the iperf.

So is there any way I can first run my iperf measurment and then while that is being done to run the ping and see the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can open plenty of xterms to do many things simultaneously.

The following code will open two Xterms for h1 and one for h2 without blocking the main CLI.

```
xterm h1 h1 h2
```